# One line assignment according condition in c/c++

Tags: c, conditional-statements, variable-assignment

Hi,

i would like to know which one of these assignments is faster, safer, better etc. and possibly why:

```c
int choice = fgetc(stdin);
unsigned int bSize;

choice = fgetc(stdin)
```

1:

```c
bSize = (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y') ? 256 : 128;
```

2:

```c
bSize = 128 + ((choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y') << 7);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Reading in the character from the file is going to eclipse the time it takes to execute either line.

Comment: Surely 1 is more readable. Whatever the compiler produces in this situation is unlikely to have a noticeable impact on performance.

Comment: @DCoder: +1 - readability is far more important in this case then minor hypothetical (and premature) micro-optimisations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding speed, this would be at least as fast as choice 2:

```
bSize = 128 << (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y');
```

Whether *that* would be faster than choice 1 is not immediately obvious to me.  However, for tuned performance on an unknown platform, I think that I like the suggested variant on choice 2.  The reason is that, at the hardware level, choice 2 (original or variant) does not involve reloading the program counter, but invokes a relatively straightforward *shift-register* operation, involving relatively few transistors.  (Actually, if you want to get really technical about it, I am given to understand that the shift is probably accomplished by *multiplexing.*  To detail that would be too much for the present  format, but the point is that the output of `(choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y')` is effectively piped straight to one of the multiplexer's control lines.  Anyway, it's really fast.)

Regarding whether one can safely use the evaluated condition in the manner suggested, ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (E), sect. 6.5.14.3, guarantees that one can safely do this.  It reads, "The || operator shall yield 1 if either of its operands compare unequal to 0; otherwise, it yields 0. The result has type int."

(@PaulR rightly observes that electronic-theoretical considerations like the ones this answer offers are not decisive.  One must profile actual code on an actual platform to tell for sure which is faster.  Nor is this a mere quibble on @PaulR's part.  It is all well to argue that choice 2 *would* be faster, but this does not mean that is *is* faster.  Depending on the CPU in use, branch-predicting or other hardware could promote choice 1, nor would I be extremely surprised if it did.)

Comment: Yeah, i guess like this it would be even faster than choice 2, still is it 100% safe to use evaluated condition as variable ?

Comment: -1: you really can't make any general predictions about the efficiency of the above examples, particularly without knowing anything about the specific compiler or platform

Comment: @Neko:  It's safe.  I have modified the answer above to explain why.

Comment: @PaulR:  Wow, you're a tough audience.  Of course you are right, but general *electronic* principles do come to bear, whether the C standard guarantees their preformance or not.  I suspect that multiplexing a bit-shift is cheaper than invoking the CPU's branch-prediction hardware, especially if the brand-predictor guesses wrong and has to flush a pipeline.  But what do I know?  Nevertheless, your point is well taken (though I'm admittedly a little grumpy about the downvote).

Comment: @thb: sorry, but it's a pet peeve of mine - making blind assumptions/predictions about performance, particularly without taking compiler and CPU into consideration, is the worst kind of premature optimisation. If performance actually matters in a given case, then *profile* the different options - evidence in the form of measured performance is infinitely more useful than guesswork.

Comment: My bad this question supposed to be more about if it's a valid and safe way of condition use. In original code i am computing carry bit like this, so there's only one condition and no additional operations. On other hand it's good to know that in both cases is compiled code the same.

Comment: @PaulR:  I have added, or done my best to add, your point to my answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion 'Choice 1' is 'faster' because there's only one assignment operation done after the comparison. In 'Choice 2' it does '+' and '<<' along with the comparison part. 'Choice 1' is 'safer' because it is more readable than the other choice so programmer will have less chance to do error in writing it. Choice 1 is 'better' because of the previous two reasons.

Comment: The only problem is that choice 1 is using branching (some compare and jump instruction), where choice 2 is not.

Comment: @Neko: You can't know whether the compiler will use branches or not, or what the penalty for branches might be without knowing details of the platform etc

Comment: -1: all predictions are meaningless without taking compiler and platform into consideration

Comment: [sorry,comments don't allow newlines]Dear Neko, I understand what you thought. But look at the code generated by 'gcc' with '-S' option:
Choice 1:

 movl %eax, -4(%rbp)
 cmpl $121, -4(%rbp)
 je .L2
 cmpl $89, -4(%rbp)
 jne .L3
.L2:
 movl $256, %eax
 jmp .L4
.L3:
 movl $128, %eax
.L4:
 movl %eax, -8(%rbp)
 movl $0, %eax
 leave

Choice 2:
 movl %eax, -4(%rbp)
 cmpl $121, -4(%rbp)
 je .L2
 cmpl $89, -4(%rbp)
 jne .L3
.L2:
 movl $1, %eax
 jmp .L4
.L3:
 movl $0, %eax
.L4:
 sall $7, %eax
 subl $-128, %eax
 movl %eax, -8(%rbp)
 movl $0, %eax
 leave

See, the L4 section in both cases. Choice is yours.

Comment: Yes, I agree with Paul R, it is Platform and/or Compiler specific.